# VBScript GetLocale returns the wrong value

Tags: vbscript, locale

I'm trying to test some scripting that will run on non-English Windows installations. I'm trying to simulate that by installing the required languages and setting my locale accordingly.

However, when I run the VBScript, I notice that the language box in the task bar changes back to en-US, and the GetLocale function always returns 1033.

What else do I need to do to properly simulate a different locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my own research, it appears to be the "Format" setting in the Region and Language control panel that corresponds with the GetLocale value.

Unfortunately, this has no bearing on the display language for the OS, which is what I was really interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Language box in the task bar has nothing to do with GetLocale.

If GetLocale is giving you 1033, your current system locale must be set to English(United States). Follow these steps to check (On Windows 7)

1. Go to Region and Language
2. Select Administrative tab
3. In the section Language for non-Unicode programs click on Change system locale

Once you change this setting, don't forget to do IISReset.

Comment: If I'm just running a script directly via Windows Script Host, does IIS still have anything to do with it?

Comment: I thought you were running it on a web page. I just tried to change it  in my machine and it asked me to reboot.